# Switch coordinates in linestring

Tags: postgis, coordinates, linestring

I made a silly mistake: when creating linestrings in my PostGis database i inverted the lon and lat values. Which isn't a problem for postgis itself, but for my visualization and intersections. ;)

Of course i only recorgnized this after importing lots of stuff. Instead of simply re-running the import i'm curios if there is a way i could swap the X/Y-Coordinates of every point of a linestring?

e.g.:

```
LINESTRING(lat1 lon1, lat2 lon2, lat3 lon3); // what i got
SomeMagicMethod();
LINESTRING(lon1 lat1, lon2 lat2, lon3 lat3); // what i want
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ST_FlipCoordinates](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_FlipCoordinates.html) (PostGIs 2.0 and up). That function was created to help people in your situation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Looks like it's exactly what i need...but i'm stuck on PostGis 1.5...

Comment: I would strongly recommend an upgrade!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

Because you are stuck on PostGIS 1.5, you can look at this example about switching the X/Y coordinates for every point of a LineString:

Presuming this is the PostGIS table:

[image]

and this is how the LineStrings looks:

[image]

you can run the code below to flip the coordinates:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  r1 RECORD;
  r2 RECORD;
  rowNo int;
  tStatement text;
  tPoint varchar;
  tNewLinestring varchar;
BEGIN
  tStatement := '';
  FOR r1 IN SELECT id_0 FROM "my_lines" LOOP
    rowNo := 0;
    tPoint := '';
    tNewLinestring := '';
    FOR r2 IN SELECT id_0, (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).geom FROM "my_lines" WHERE id_0 = r1.id_0 LOOP
      rowNo := rowNo + 1;
      tPoint := ST_Y(ST_AsText(r2.geom)) || ' ' || ST_X(ST_AsText(r2.geom)) || ',';
      tNewLinestring := tNewLinestring || tPoint;
    END LOOP;
    tNewLinestring := '''' || 'LINESTRING(' || trim(trailing ',' from tNewLinestring) || ')' || '''';
    tStatement := 'UPDATE "my_lines" ' || 'SET "geom" = ST_GeomFromText('
                  || tNewLinestring || ', 4326) WHERE id_0 = ' || r1.id_0;
 -- RAISE NOTICE 'statement2: %', tStatement;
    EXECUTE tStatement;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END$$;
```

to obtain the following result:

[image]

---

**Solution 2:**

Bellow is a quick and dirt solution to solve the coordinates switching. (**This time, using no code!**)

- *Step 1:* Add your PostGIS table as a layer into QGIS:

[image]

- *Step 2:* Install the Swap XY plugin.
- *Step 3:* Press the Swap XY button in the plugin toolbar:

[image]

- *Step 4:* Import your shapefile back to PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. But i finally solved it with a small perl-script i hacked together ;)